# None of the commands work in centos

Tags: centos, glibc

I have made a big mistake while removing some duplicate packages as it appears to be broken. yum

```
 1036  rpm -e --nodeps glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64
 1037  rpm -e --nodeps nscd-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64
 1038  rpm -e --nodeps glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64
 1040  rpm -e --nodeps glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 glibc-headers-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
 1041  rpm -e glibc.x86_64
 1042  rpm -e --nodeps glibc.x86_64
```

The issue happened after doing 1042 step. **None of commands work(including yum, rpm, ls)** and getting error

*/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory*

I thought that installing glibc after removing all the current ones would help to resolve the duplicate package error :( Now I realised that it is used as the C library in the GNU system and most systems with the Linux kernel. It defines the "system calls" and other basic facilities such as open, malloc, printf, exit, etc.

Is there any possible solutions **other than reinstall**?

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)...  But one thing you could do is boot from a Live CD/DVD/USB and copy the files you need back in place...

Comment: okay, I will..its a kvm vps not sure whether I can boot from cd since memory is too low(256M)